# Outlook downloading files, rather than opening in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, outlook, hyperlink

When I receive an email in Outlook that has a link to a document on SharePoint, the link just downloads the file to be opened by my locally installed Office 2010.  I've figured out that this happens when the sender links to the email by using the "Email a Link" function in SharePoint.  However, when the user right clicks the document and just copy and pastes the link to the document in an email, it will open right up in SharePoint like I want it to.

Is there something I can do on my end so that the files are never downloaded, but rather always opened in SharePoint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Probably your list has the option "browserfilehanding" set to "Permissive". Change it to "Strict":

```
$site = Get-SPSite("http://SharePointSite")
 $web = $site.OpenWeb()
 $list = $web.GetList("http://SharePointSite/Attachments")

 write-output $list.browserfilehandling
if ($list.browserfilehandling -eq "Permissive")
{

 $list.browserfilehandling = “Strict” ;
 $list.update();

}
```

Comment: You cannot use the server object model in PowerShell in SPO.